# Cocoa tableview overview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tableview

I am really new to Cocoa and I am working on a test app with a NSMutableArray with NSDictionary objects as childs. Eventually I want to be able to add/edit/display the array using a tableview.

I have a class which on init creates the NSMutableArray and has methods to add objects to the array. Should the class have the: numberOfRowsInTableView and tableView methods? Or should I separate them from my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the numberOfRowsInTableView and other tableView datasource and delegate methods in the class that you have set as the datasource and delegate.  You can put them in your main class for ease of passing variables, or if you know how to get variables from other classes, feel free to make a (Initials)TableView class to hold the delegate and datasource methods.

Comment: Though an array controller with Cocoa bindings is a lot, a lot easier.

Comment: Agreed. http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000080.php is a good tutorial on how to use basic bindings.  Much easier than anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. At the moment I have a implemented the model in the controller(for ease of passing variables, as tlunter mentioned). But that doesn't follow the MVC rules, right? If Bindings are a lot easier, I will definitely be taking a look at them.

Comment: Take a look at bindings.  There are tons of other resources about bindings including Apple's Documentation.  If you find that hard to read, look into a program called Ingredients.  It will make it easier to sort through the documentation.  Bindings made making a program take a month to a week because of its simplicity.